# Creating Cache Conflict in assembly

Tags: assembly, caching, cpu-architecture, riscv, riscv32

Cache Size: 4 KB By Default
Line Size : 32 Bytes
Address Bits division:
Number of sets: Cache Size/ 2x line size (multiplying by two as we have two way set associative cache) = 4096/2x32 = 64 Sets
1- Offset Bits: As cache line size is 32 B so we have 5 Bits for offset
2- Set Index: As there are 64 sets so we have 6 bits for set index
3- Tag: Remaining 21 Bits for Tag

I want to access multiple different addresses which map to same sets in the instruction cache and when I access the third one which maps to the same set it should evict the other lines!

I have tried the following:

```
  #Loop to repeat accesses 
  li    x3, 0

  la    t0, jump_inst_set_0
  la    t1, jump_inst_set_1
  la    s1, jump_inst_set_0_1
  la    t2, wfi_label
  
  jalr  t0

  skip_wfi:
  addi s0, s0, 1
  jal wfi_label
  
  addi x3, x3, 1
  li x4, 5
  bne x3, x4, repeat

  exit_tst


.org 0x3000
.align 2
jump_inst_set_0:
  jr  t1

.org 0x4000
.align 2
jump_inst_set_1:
  jr  s1

.org 0x5000
.align 2
jump_inst_set_0_1:
  jr  t2

.org 0x6000
.align 2
wfi_label:
beq s0, x0, skip_wfi
  add x0, x0, x0
  ret
```

The idea here is to set some addresses in memory that are mapping to same set as per the defined sizes and when I access those addresses I get cache conflicts!

Comment: Ok, and your question is what?

Comment: I want to ask that how will I observe/be sure/confirm that these conflicts are taking place or not? Bcz I only have access to couple of dump files and can look at the CPU signals but not at cache memory! Let me know if you need further explanation! @ErikEidt